# MS Excel - existing connection strings correspond to which datatable

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that has 8 connections. I would like to know what connection string corresponds to which datatable/pivot table in excel. A solution in 2007 or 2010 method is fine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using the Data tab.

Try this:

-- Click on **Connections** in the **Data** tab to bring up the **Workbook Connections** dialog.

[image: Excel Data --> Connections]

-- Click on a connection in the list.

[image: List of Workbook Connections]

-- Click the link: **click here to see where the selected connections are used**

[image: Show where data connections are used in Workbook]

Comment: That was it. Odd how Microsoft made that link in black text. Didn't really stand out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible from VBA too. This query just enumerates them.

You can readily modify this example to refresh the queries using `PivotCache.Refresh` or `QueryTable.Refresh`.

```
Sub ShowAllQueryConnectionStrings()
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each oSheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Dim oTable As Excel.QueryTable
        For Each oTable In oSheet.QueryTables
            Debug.Print "QueryTable " & oTable.Name & ": " & oTable.Connection
        Next
        Dim oPivot As Excel.PivotTable
        For Each oPivot In oSheet.PivotTables
            Debug.Print "PivotTable " & oPivot.Name & ": " & oPivot.PivotCache.Connection
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```